# Reorder ALAssets

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

Does anyone know how to reorder assets in the assets library? Does ALAsset have something like an order property that I can use to change the order of the asset? What is the default ordering when I enumerate the assets?

Answer (score 13):

It's possible for date. You need to create a category for ALAsset with the following method

```
// in the .h
- (NSDate *) date;

// in the .m
- (NSDate *) date
{
    return [self valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
}
```

Then add all of the assets to an NSMutableArray and sort that array like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
self.assets = [tmpAssets sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

I have a tutorial here and this will be discussed in detail in the second part (due out later this week).

[iPhone Programming Tutorial: Creating An Image Gallery Like Over – Part 1](http://brandontreb.com/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-an-image-gallery-like-over-part-1)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can't get it to work, i got the same result with ascending YES and NO.
Any help?

Comment: Works perfectly : To create a category for ALAsset :
File -> New -> File -> Source -> Objective-C file -> File Type: Category + Class: ALAsset

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible using public APIs. If you want to see that feature in the future, please leave a feature request at http://bugreport.apple.com